# The amazing migration of a medical question to an English-language site

Tags: discussion

My [question about a clinical trial report](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/482957/48335) was for some unknown reason migrated to EL&U.

I'd be pleased to know why.

Comment: You've asked a whole series of questions that are a mix of English usage and medical knowledge. This one in particular appeared to me to be a question about language, not medicine. If you really feel it's a question about medical science and not language, then I'll have the EL&U mods migrate it back but once they do you'll need to edit to clarify that what you're asking is more than language usage.

Comment: I also note that you got a pretty good answer on EL&U.

Comment: I see the answer and think it's pretty good.  If all else fails though, Academia might even be a better fit for it, as it's basically about wording in a research paper. I am not sure you'll get a definitive answer anywhere since I agree, the wording is poor in the paper itself.

Comment: @CareyGregory I also note that the question got closed as off-topic on EL&U.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Do you have a better suggestion where it should go? It's a difficult question with no clear cut home.